# space is coming between two segments in segmented control

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have updated my app to ios7. But some space is coming between two segments in segmented control

The code :

```
 [self.mSegment setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimg1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [self.mSegment setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimg2.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        self.mSegment.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I dont want to set the divider image in my code as per my project requirements

```
 [self.mSegment setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_line.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance